# Need to check if folder has Read and Execute permissions in c# and it should fails when the user has only List contents permissions

Tags: c#

I tried checking the permissions of directory which has only List folder contents permissions for the current user but still it returns true for the below piece of code.

```
        WindowsIdentity currentuser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        var domainAndUser = currentuser.Name;
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(downloadSource.BasePath);
        DirectorySecurity dirAC = dirInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);
        AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = dirAC.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
        foreach(AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
        {
          if (rule.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(domainAndUser, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                        if ((((FileSystemAccessRule)rule).FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute) > 0 )
                        return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: If I use GetAccessControl it also fails for the locations in which user does not have write access. I also tried using Directory.GetFiles(path) but this executes with List contents permission. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a simple bit logic error

Suppose you have flags

```
read = 1
execute = 2
ReadAndExecute = 3
```

and result

```
FileSystemRights = 1 (read only, no execute)
```

then

```
((FileSystemRights & ReadAndExecute) > 0) is true
```

So try the following check instead:

```
if ((((FileSystemAccessRule)rule).FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute) == FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute)
```

It will check that not *any* but *all* flags from `ReadAndExecute` are required.

Alternative, use the enum flag check:

```
if ((((FileSystemAccessRule)rule).FileSystemRights).HasFlag(FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute))
```